# How to move selected matrix rows to top of matrix based on a selection vector of row names

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix that has been ordered by `rowSums()`. I now want to take a selected few of these rows, by passing a char vector of row names, and easily move them back at the top of the matrix ***while keeping the moved rows in the same order as they are in the selection vector***.

I've tried to do this with various combinations of `subset()` or just straight index selection, but I can never get the resulting matrix in the order I want, if it works at all. I feel like there has to be a more straightforward way to do this.

Let's say I have a matrix `mat` ordered by `rowSums()`:

```
      sam1 sam2 sam3 sam4 sam5
sig1     1    2    3    4    5
sig2     6    7    8    9   10
sig3    11   12   13   14   15
sig4a   16   17   18   19   20
sig4b   21   22   23   24   25
sig4c   26   27   28   29   30
sig5    31   32   33   34   35
sig6    36   37   38   39   40
sig7a   41   42   43   44   45
aig7b   46   47   48   49   50
```

And I want to take a select number of rows I'm interested in:

```
select = c('sig6','sig4a','sig2')
```

And move them back to the top of the matrix, while **keeping them in the order** in the `select` vector, while leaving the remaining unselected rows below them to get a new matrix:

```
      sam1 sam2 sam3 sam4 sam5
sig6    36   37   38   39   40 *
sig4a   16   17   18   19   20 *
sig2     6    7    8    9   10 *
sig1     1    2    3    4    5
sig3    11   12   13   14   15
sig4b   21   22   23   24   25
sig4c   26   27   28   29   30
sig5    31   32   33   34   35
sig7a   41   42   43   44   45
aig7b   46   47   48   49   50
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this that doesn't involve making intermediate matrices or complicated workarounds? It seems like there should be, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Maybe I am overlooking something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to specify the vector of row names first followed by the ones that are left with `setdiff`

```
mat[c(select, setdiff(row.names(mat), select)),]
#.     sam1 sam2 sam3 sam4 sam5
#sig6    36   37   38   39   40
#sig4a   16   17   18   19   20
#sig2     6    7    8    9   10
#sig1     1    2    3    4    5
#sig3    11   12   13   14   15
#sig4b   21   22   23   24   25
#sig4c   26   27   28   29   30
#sig5    31   32   33   34   35
#sig7a   41   42   43   44   45
#aig7b   46   47   48   49   50
```

#### data

```
mat <- structure(c(1L, 6L, 11L, 16L, 21L, 26L, 31L, 36L, 41L, 46L, 2L, 
7L, 12L, 17L, 22L, 27L, 32L, 37L, 42L, 47L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 18L, 
23L, 28L, 33L, 38L, 43L, 48L, 4L, 9L, 14L, 19L, 24L, 29L, 34L, 
39L, 44L, 49L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 35L, 40L, 45L, 50L
), .Dim = c(10L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("sig1", "sig2", "sig3", 
"sig4a", "sig4b", "sig4c", "sig5", "sig6", "sig7a", "aig7b"), 
    c("sam1", "sam2", "sam3", "sam4", "sam5")))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I would have hoped there would be a simpler way to do this though like a `move(c('row6','row7'), c(1,2))` or something like that.

Comment: @Leo. You can create a function with `setdiff` and make it more simpler